# How do I join MySQL tables with JSON fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables which I would like perform a join query.

Sensors is a table, where the records refer to sensor metadata.
Combinations is a table to combine multiple sensor data into a single one based on some user-defined formula.

Sensors:

```
| sensor_id | attribute | operating_voltage | ... |
| 1         | temp      | 5V                | ... |
| 2         | humidity  | 5V                | ... |
| 3         | count     | 5V                | ... |
| 4         | count     | 5V                | ... |
```

Combinations:

```
| combination_id | formula | formula_mapping | ... |
| 1              | x + y   | { x: 3, y: 4 }  | ... |
| 2              | x * y   | { x: 1, y: 3 }  | ... |
```

I want to select all combinations, inner join with sensors which are referenced by the JSON keys defined in the combinations.formula_mapping column. I tried to use

```
SELECT * FROM combinations 
INNER JOIN sensors 
  ON json_contains(combinations.formula_mapping, sensors.sensor_id, '$.*');
```

However, wildcard * don't seem to be allowed. And all the other methods JSON_KEYS, JSON_EXTRACT etc. seem to require a specific path to be defined for the query. Is it possible to perform 1 join query with the above schema? Or would I then have to query combinations first, before doing another query?

Edited to include query results expected:

```
| combination_id | sensor_id |
| 1              | 3         |
| 1              | 4         |
| 2              | 1         |
| 2              | 3         |
```

Comment: What is the expected result (as per the given sample data) ? Edit the question to add expected output in tabular format.

Comment: @Madhur edited to include expected results

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Json_Search()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function instead:

```
SELECT * FROM combinations AS c
INNER JOIN sensors AS s
  ON JSON_SEARCH(c.formula_mapping, 'one', s.sensor_id) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Tried this but its returning me a null set, will try to explore more on JSON_SEARCH function, thanks anyway!

Comment: @jlyh can you setup a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) , so that I can try with your sample data. Read: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Hi @Madhur Bhaiya I think its because of a bug in JSON_SEARCH where it doesn't work with non-string values - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233

Comment: Thanks @jlyh for the noteworthy information. I tried other json function combinations, but nothing seem to work. I think that the better solution would be to change the way Json is stored. Instead of storing the values as integer; you can store them as string. eg: `'{"x":"1","y":"2"}'`